# replace Notificaion.requestPermission() dialog with html dialog

Tags: javascript, html, browser, permissions, notifications

I need to request permission from user to send notifications , so I use this code

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(...).catch(...);
```

this will shows this dialog

[image]

but I want to replace this dialog with one from html , a dialog like this

[image]

I searched many times but did not find any thing that can help me .

Answer (score 2):

You can't because of security reasons, imagine somebody create a custom html dialog, which show `Block` and `Allow` buttons, but both act like `Allow`.